# Numpy covariance command returning matrix with more dimensions than input

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

I have an arbitrary row vector "u" and an arbitrary matrix "e" as follows:

```
u = np.resize(np.array([8,3]),[1,2])
e = np.resize(np.array([[2,2,5,5],[1, 6, 7, 4]]),[4,2])
np.cov(u,e)

array([[ 12.5,   0. ,   0. , -12.5,   7.5],
   [  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],
   [  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],
   [-12.5,   0. ,   0. ,  12.5,  -7.5],
   [  7.5,   0. ,   0. ,  -7.5,   4.5]])
```

The matrix that this returns is 5x5. This is confusing to me because the largest dimension of the inputs is only 4.

Thus, this may be less of a numpy question and more of a math question...not sure...

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the official numpy documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) and check whether you usage of the numpy.cov function is consistent with what you are trying to achieve and you understand what you are trying to do.

When looking at the signature

> numpy.cov(m, y=None, rowvar=True, bias=False, ddof=None, fweights=None, aweights=None)
>
> m : array_like
>
> A 1-D or 2-D array containing multiple variables and observations. 
>      Each row of m represents a variable, and each column a single observation > >    of all those variables. Also see rowvar below.
>
> y : array_like, optional
>
> An additional set of variables and observations. y has the same form as that of m.

Note how m and y are combined as shown in the last example on the page

```
>>> x = [-2.1, -1,  4.3]
>>> y = [3,  1.1,  0.12]
>>> X = np.stack((x, y), axis=0)
>>> print(np.cov(X))
[[ 11.71        -4.286     ]
[ -4.286        2.14413333]]
>>> print(np.cov(x, y))
[[ 11.71        -4.286     ]
[ -4.286        2.14413333]]
>>> print(np.cov(x))
11.71
```